# Java: Why does if statement never resolve to true?

Tags: java, if-statement, user-input

I am trying to make a noughts-and-crosses prototype. The section of code I am struggling with is getting an user input, and if the input is *y*, it should change the gamestate to `0` which restarts the game. However this doesn't happen. Can anyone explain why?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
                if (s.next().toLowerCase() == "y") {
                    System.out.println("Okay");
                    g.gamestate = 0;
                } else {
                    g.gamestate = 4;
                }
```

Comment: because you use `==` instead of equals. SO how to compare strings

Comment: use `equals` method don't use `==` to compare `String`

Comment: Thank you, I've not been told about using equals instead of == before, I was also unaware that this was called "comparing strings".

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `s.next().toLowerCase().equals("y")`
Operator "==" comparing the links on your string objects, and method "equals" comparing values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as somebody commented the solution is need to use `equals()` instead of `==`.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
  if (s.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
      System.out.println("Okay");
      //g.gamestate = 0;
  } else {
      System.out.println("No");
     // g.gamestate = 4;
  }
```

Comment: as per OP, he needs y in lower case. So need of equalsIgnoreCase, only equals is needed

Comment: Yes, you are right!